# Rigorous notation for "approaching" a limit from a certain direction

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm doing a small course in complex analysis and limits have come to discussion. The limit that's the cause of the question is

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin|z|}{z}$$

After some manipulations, I was able to get this to the following form:

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin|z|\cdot\bar z}{|z|^2}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin|z|}{|z|}\cdot\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\bar z}{|z|}$$

The first limit is obviously equal to $1,$ and that leaves me with the second limit. Switching to a multivariable calculus notation, we'd have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x-yi}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

If we approach $(0,0)$ from above, taking $\epsilon > 0$ we'll get the following limit:

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{-\epsilon i}{\epsilon} = -i$$

Though if the limit is approached from below:

$$\lim_{-\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\epsilon i}{\epsilon} = i$$

Which shows the expression does not have a limit. My question is, is this way of dealing with directional limits adequate for complex analysis?

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct, although overcomplicated. Please observe that your limit does not exist for a real function.

And obtaining different limits is a standard way of proving that a limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is adequate and in fact quite useful. The polar representation of complex numbers, i.e. $z=re^{i\theta}$ with $r=|z|$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi)$, emphasizes clearly the direction of a complex number. So, by the definition of the limit, it follows that the existence of the limit $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin |z|}{z}$ is equivalent to the existence of the limit of $\frac{\sin r}{re^{i\theta}}$ when $r\to 0$, **regardless of $\theta$**, which is clearly not the case. In fact, the limit along a ray of angle $\theta$ is equal to $e^{-i\theta}$.